# Request Cancellation is not propagated to cloud run container

Tags: google-cloud-run

When an HTTP request sent to a cloud run service is cancelled by the initiating service, the cancelled/closed connection is not propagated to the request that is being serviced inside the cloud run container.

Example code:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ctx := r.Context()
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            log.Printf("context cancelled")
        case <-time.After(time.Minute):
            w.Write([]byte("OK"))
            log.Printf("request completed. path=%s", r.URL.Path)
        }
    })
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil))
}
```

Running this code locally, a curl request sent to http://localhost:8080 and then cancelled with ctrl-c will show up in the logs as "context cancelled". The same request with the service deployed in cloud run and cancelled will show up as a successful request after 1 minute in the logs.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think Cloud Run offers such a guarantee today.

I am guessing this is because of an implementation detail. The external traffic to a Run service does not directly go to the container, but rather passes through one or more load balancers and proxies. These LBs/proxies may not be properly propagating the client disconnects (or simply buffering requests/responses). This would result in the behavior you’re seeing.

I will go ahead and file an internal feature request about it. Thanks for bringing it up.

Comment: Did this get implemented? I've look at the public issue tracker for Cloud Run but did not see any mention of the issue there, and can't find anything in the documentation. I'd expect it to be the intended behaviour.

Comment: No, not yet implemented.

Comment: This would still be a nice behavior to have. To be able to propagate a request close event to the cloud run server.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [HTTP2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2) when you deploy the cloud run container `ctx.Done()` works:

```
    gcloud run deploy <SERVICE_NAME>\
        --project <GPC_PROJECT_ID>\
        --allow-unauthenticated\
        --use-http2 \
        -q\
        --region europe-west1\
        --platform managed\
        --image <CONTAINER_NAME>
```

Full example: https://github.com/karl-gustav/minimal-sse/blob/main/main.go